# Convert raw SQL query to Django ORM with multiple joins

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have this raw query which I need to rewrite in Django's ORM:

```
SELECT count(u.username) as user_count, l.id as level_id, l.name as level_name
FROM users u
JOIN user_levels ul ON ul.username = u.username
JOIN sub_levels sl ON sl.id = ul.current_sub_level_id
JOIN levels l ON l.id = sl.level_id
WHERE u.created_at::DATE >= '2018-01-01' AND u.created_at::DATE <= '2018-01-17' AND u.type = 'u'
GROUP BY l.id, l.name
```

So far I have been able to write it in this way:

```
Users.objects.select_related('user_levels', 'sub_levels', 'levels')
.filter(created_at__date__gte='2018-01-01', created_at__date__lte='2018-01-17', type='u')
.values('userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level_id', 'userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level__name')
.annotate(user_count=Count('username'))
```

The output has `"userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level_id"` and `"userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level__name"` columns. I need them aliased as `"level_id"` and `"level_name"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **F() expression** is suitable in this context. Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F

Users.objects.select_related('user_levels', 'sub_levels', 'levels')
.filter(created_at__date__gte='2018-01-01', created_at__date__lte='2018-01-17', type='u')
.annotate(level_id=F('userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level_id'), level_name=F('userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level__name'))
.values('level_id', 'level_name')
.annotate(user_count=Count('username'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **F() expressions** ?

You can use it in this way.

```
from django.db.models import F

queryset.annotate(final_name=F('selected_name'))
```

For more information check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

Don't forget to change the values with final_name(s).

Comment: I wrote the query with F() object in annotate, this is returning me the desired keys "level_id" and "level_name" along with "userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level_id" and "userlevel__current_sub_level_id__level__name". Is there no way to avoid these 2 long keys too?

Comment: @AnkitaGupta yes, just remove them from values.

>>print(User.objects.annotate(user_name=F('username')).values('user_name')[0]) 
>>{'user_name': 'davit'}

Comment: This is not helping because I need to apply grouping on level_id and name. If I move .values() after annotate(), the grouping doesn't take place